# how to post image with Math.random

Tags: javascript, html

How do i post X number of images where X=random number. In this example i have set X=10

```
<input class="randombutton" type="button" value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomImg1() {

        myImages1 = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        myImages1.push("MyImage" + i + ".jpg");
}

        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "' alt='image' />";
}
    randomImg1();
</script>
<div id="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: myImages1 is not an array of images.  You first need to create an array with src of images.

Comment: i have just edit it and it is still not working

Comment: Are you going for a single random image? or is the number of images to be displayed random?

Comment: @SørenPhithak You are missing a `)` after `.push` (it's a small p btw).

Comment: @asifrc iam going for 1 single image, and the number of images to be displayed random.

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks but it is still not working

Comment: @SørenPhithak Do you get any error in your javascript console? The console is the most useful tool for debugging this sort of stuff. If I paste this into my javascript console it works fine, so your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @h2ooooooo it is not working as i want it to cuz the other guys misinterpreted my question i want it to post my image not randomizer it. the (Math.random() * 10); have to generate numbers of how many image that i can see on my screen. like 1-10 i get 4 and i can see image-image-image-image on my screen

Answer (score 0):

You declare the function but you don't call it. In addition, you have to use `Array.prototype.push` instead of `=` for adding an element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input class="randombutton" type="button" value="Randomize" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomImg1() {

    myImages1 = new Array();
    myImages1.push("MyImage.jpg");
    var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );

    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "' alt='image'></img>";
}
    randomImg1();
</script>
<div id="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

FYI, the chances are high that this still does not work in most cases because your array has only 1 element, but `1 <= rnd <= 10`.

Comment: i have just try your code out but no image show up when i push the button

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array then assigning that very same variable a string value, it's no longer an array.

Try something like this:

```
myImages1 = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myImages1.push("MyImage" + i + ".jpg");
}

var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "' alt='image' />";
```

You will also need to hook the button up to call this function, this can be done as follows:

```
<input class="randombutton" type="button" value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg1" />
```

Complete tested code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function randomImg1()
            {
                myImages1 = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    myImages1.push("MyImage" + i + ".jpg");
                }

                var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

                document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "' alt='image' />";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="randombutton" type="button" value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg1()" />

        <div id="image"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have just edit my code on top am i missing something it still not working

Comment: You need to tell your button to call the function when it is clicked, see my edit.

Comment: I just noticed a typo, I forgot to close a bracket and push was upper case. Can you correct these in your code, verify that you're getting no script errors in your browser and try again?

Comment: I close the bracket on push but wnat is the upper case ?

Comment: I typed Push instead of push, the first letter shouldn't be capitalised. Do you have any script errors in your browser's javascript console?

Comment: it is saying : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Is that the only element on the page with `id="image"`?

Comment: Apparently I also missed the brackets from the function call in the onclick code. See my edit for full tested code.

Comment: i have try your code now and it says: Failed to load resource i dont know why

Comment: That's good! That means the javascript has worked and the image element has been added to the page, it just can't find it. You'll need to make sure that an image with that name exists in the same folder as the html page. But other than that you're good to go =]

Comment: i think you misinterpreted my question i dont know it to display random image i want it to post my image like: random=5, then i click and get 3 = image-image-image.

Comment: like i can see 3 image on my page because the (Math.random() * 10);  genarate the nr. 3

Comment: Oh well in that case you're into the realm of making HTTP Requests in JavaScript and I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're searching for (if I've understood you correctly) is the following:

```
function randomImg1() {
    var imageAmount = Math.random() * 10;
    var imagesHTMLBuffer = "";

    var imagePath;
    for (var i = 0; i < imageAmount; i++)
    {
        imagePath = "MyImage" + i + ".jpg";
        imagesHTMLBuffer += '<img src="' + imagePath + '" alt="image" />';
    }

    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = imagesHTMLBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show a random number (max. 10) of random images:

### HTML

```
<div id="random-image-container"></div>
```

### Javascript

```
var numberOfImages = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

var imageContainer = document.getElementById('random-image-container');

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++)
{
    var randomImage = 'http://placekitten.com/' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + '/' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    imageContainer.innerHTML += '<img src="' + randomImage + '" />';
}
```

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZThe/